# Fabric Network Non-Fatal

Tags: android, retrofit2, crashlytics, okhttp, google-fabric

I have these Non-Fatals in Fabric, I have to make sure i understand these non-fatal well and there is no action from my side.

**Is it correct to ignore reporting them?**

[image]
[image]
**Reason**
[image]
**What I Understand:** 
This non fatal happens when the user tries to access the app without internet access.

[image]
[image]
**Reason**
[image]
**What I Understand:** 
This non fatal happens when there is a timeout from API or Device Network.

[image]
[image]
**Reason**
[image]
**What I Understand:** 
This non fatal happens when the user has Internet connections but the can't connect to API.

[image]
[image]
**Reason**
[image]

**What I Understand:** 
This non fatal happens when the API close the connection

[image]
[image]
**Reason**
[image]
**What I Understand:** 
This non fatal happens when custom proxy in device config.

Comment: How about show "Network untable" toast message if timeout?
And if user do not have internet connection also show "No internet connection" message.

Comment: I have internal code to check if there are internet connections or not, I have custom error screens for those cases.

Comment: But are these non-fatal normal?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it correct to ignore reporting them?

Depends on you, any error is a user satisfaction hit. The crash is more present because it distracts the user from what he was doing in the harshest way.

The non-fatal error still is an error, that breaks some functionality of your app.

**Regarding your case, looks like you can't do anything about such error since users have problems with internet connections.**

Speaking of such errors in the first place, you set them by yourself in the try-catch blocks

```
try {
  myMethodThatThrows();
} catch (Exception e) {
  Crashlytics.logException(e);
  // handle your exception here!
}
```

It would send that non-fatal to your fabric dashboard. You could read more about them here: [Caught Exceptions](https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/caught-exceptions.html#caught-exceptions)